# Can I use "--allow-file-access-from-files" when starting chrome app?

Tags: file, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app

I am trying to load a simple .txt file content with a Chrome App (using `file:` protocol); I need to show its content for the user in a `<div>`. I need to open the file from a path typed in a input text (or defined in a string variable).

The flag `--allow-file-access-from-files` works fine when I load my .txt file content through Chrome browser. However, when I try to do the same with my Chrome App launcher (I have applied `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag on it), it keeps telling

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I dont know if I am missing something or if it is impossible for chrome app. 
My user will work with the app in Windows platform.

Comment: Use [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) instead.

Comment: Possible solutions are given in SO post - [How to launch html using Chrome at “--allow-file-access-from-files” mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode) Hope it works for you too. :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37029737/934239 - can't close since answer wasn't upvoted or accepted.

Comment: No, Xan. I don't think it is duplicate. The other question does not mention the flag at all. I finally figured out that the "--allow-file-access-from-files" does not work at all in my case. I started coding using fileSystem and made something like the recomended in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209773/chrome-app-create-and-write-to-file ,following the main example https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/filesystem-access/js/app.js

Comment: It is a duplicate, in that the answer addresses your question ("can't use `file://`  in apps" and proposes a solution)

Comment: Also - please don't edit questions to incorporate a "Solved: (solution)" part. It's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question, and this will show others that the question HAS answers.

Comment: I accept it as a similar question as the other one that I have found since it does not make reference to the flag. There is references about using this flag but within the browser. I understand your point of view however my question cannot be answered by a question that does not mention the flag (my question title) in both body and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that `--allow-file-access-from-files` does not work at all in my case.

I started coding using `fileSystem` and made something like the recomended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209773/chrome-app-create-and-write-to-file), following the main [example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/filesystem-access/js/app.js). Now I am able to work with files in a directory asking the user to choose it only one time.